# Firebase dashboard doesn't show price in top products

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In the Firebase dashboard, when looking at the add_to_cart event, I can see the price parameter firing with values succesfully: 
[image]

But then below, in the "top products" window, I cannot see any prices:
[image]

I'm trying to understand why. Is it because I'm not sending the value parameter (I'm only sending the price and currency)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events summary in your first screenshot shows the `price` parameter sent. This could be a string, a number, anything. In your case it's a number.

The products summary in your second screenshot shows the `value` parameter sent. This must be a monetary value, and is what you should be using.

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#VALUE):

> **public static final String VALUE**
>
> A context-specific numeric value which is accumulated automatically
>   for each event type. Value should be specified with `putLong(String, long)` or `putDouble(String, double)`. This is a general purpose
>   parameter that is useful for accumulating a key metric that pertains
>   to an event. Examples include revenue, distance, time, and points.
>   Notes: Values for pre-defined currency-related events (such as
>   ADD_TO_CART) should be accompanied by a `CURRENCY` param. The valid
>   range of accumulated values is `[-9,223,372,036,854.77, 9,223,372,036,854.77]`. Supplying a non-numeric value, omitting the
>   corresponding `CURRENCY` parameter, or supplying an invalid currency
>   code for conversion events will cause that conversion to be omitted
>   from reporting.
>
> ```
>  Bundle params = new Bundle();
>  params.putDouble(Param.VALUE, 3.99);
>  params.putString(Param.CURRENCY, "USD" );  // e.g. $3.99 USD
> ```