# Firebase - How to see the values for the "Product revenue" and "Average price" of the "Top products" report?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm having trouble when working with the add_to_cart event as I'm not able to see the values for both the "Product revenue" and "Average price" columns of the "Top products" report even though the "value" parameter is being tracked on the console. See the following screenshots below:

[Tracking the value parameter on the Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsTam.png)

[Top products report displaying zero for both Product revenue and Average price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK8xO.png)

I was following the Firebase's [Measure Ecommerce](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerce#swift_4) guide, but still no success and I really don't know why. Do you know if there's a Firebase bug on this?

If you need to take a look at the code I'm using, check the two ways I used:

Option 1: Handling every parameter value on the same dictionary.

```
    let jeggings: [String: Any] = [
       AnalyticsParameterItemID: "11111",
       AnalyticsParameterItemName: "jeggings"
       AnalyticsParameterItemCategory: "pants",
       AnalyticsParameterItemVariant: "black",
       AnalyticsParameterItemBrand: "brand",
       AnalyticsParameterPrice: 19.99,
       AnalyticsParameterQuantity: 5,
       AnalyticsParameterCurrency: "USD",
       AnalyticsParameterValue: 99.95
    ]
    
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventAddToCart, parameters: jeggings)
```

Option 2: Handling the items on a list.

```
    var jeggings: [String: Any] = [
      AnalyticsParameterItemID: "11111",
      AnalyticsParameterItemName: "jeggings",
      AnalyticsParameterItemCategory: "pants",
      AnalyticsParameterItemVariant: "black",
      AnalyticsParameterItemBrand: "brand",
      AnalyticsParameterPrice: 19.99,
      AnalyticsParameterQuantity: 5,
      AnalyticsParameterCurrency: "USD",
      AnalyticsParameterValue: 99.95
    ]
    
    jeggings[AnalyticsParameterQuantity] = 5

    var itemDetails: [String: Any] = [
      AnalyticsParameterCurrency: "USD",
      AnalyticsParameterValue: 121.42
    ]
    
    itemDetails[AnalyticsParameterItems] = [jeggings]
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventAddToCart, parameters: itemDetails)
```

Sadly, the answer on this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072752/firebase-dashboard-doesnt-show-price-in-top-products) didn't help me on this.

Comment: have you ever been able to solve the problem?